# Explaining Object Oriented Programming with an object declaration and instantiation

Tags: java, oop, collections, polymorphism

```
HashMap myMap = new HashMap<Character, Character>();

Map myMap = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
```

What is a more technical way to describe the difference between the two above lines of code, in terms of object oriented programming and polymorphism during an interview?

A non technical way seems like it would be:

The left side of the equals sign is how we "talk" to the object, the right said is what the object actually is.  The left side could be an interface, but the right has to be an instantiable class since we can't instantiate an interface.

Comment: Additionally, both examples are raw-types in Java; and both are thus "wrong". Don't use raw-types.

Answer (score 0):

A more technical way to describe them is that in the first line you're declaring a variable named `myMap` of type `HashMap` and instantiating it as an object of same type `HashMap`. In the second line, you're declaring a variable named `myMap` of type `Map` and instantiating it as an object of type `HashMap` which is possible by leveraging polymorphism due to the hierarchical class relationship between object types `Map` and `HashMap`.